# Python adding machine

Tags: python, calculator

I was wondering if there is any way to make this code smaller/condensed. It is for a school project which says it has to be as small as it can be and I am not sure whether it can go any smaller.

```
num1 = float(input("Give first number "))#Get first number
num2 = float(input("Give second number ")) #Get second number
ans = num1 + num2 #Work out answer
if ans % 1 == 0: #If its a whole number
    print (int(ans)) #Convert to int so its for example 14 instead of 14.0
else: #If not a whole number
    print (ans) #Print the answer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without actually code-golfing, there are still a few shortenings possible:

```
def ask(n):
    return float(input("Give %s number " % n))

ans = ask("first") + ask("second")
print(int(ans) if not ans % 1 else ans)
```

This uses a function for asking for the numbers, does not store the intermediate values, uses a ternary expression for printing and the fact that zero evaluates to `False`.

---

If you actually want it as small as possible (in bytes), this is a start, but can probably be golfed down a lot further (e.g. by encoding the strings):

```
a=lambda n:float(input("Give %s number "%n))
r=a("first")+a("second")
print((int(r),r)[r%1>0])
```

Have a look at the tips for [golfing in python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python).

If you also want to forego the interface:

```
r=sum(float(input())for _ in"_"*2)
print((int(r),r)[r%1>0])
```

Comment: Since the function body is a single expression, you could make it a `lambda` and eliminate the `return`.

Comment: @200_success Thanks, edited. I'm not a code-golfer, but this is so much fun, I might actually try it :)

Comment: Could you explain how  this works in more detail please?   print(int(ans) if not ans % 1 else ans)

Comment: @LSmith `ans % 1` returns either `0` or not. `0` is considered False in python, so `not ans % 1` is `True` for whole numbers (where the mode gives 0). This is used in a ternary expression which are of the format `expression1 if condition else expression2` in python.